# How to load html files into excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

We periodically get a set of SQL queries outputs in the form of a html file. So, basically, this html file contains a set of SQL output in tabular form, which I can right-click and open it in MS Excel.

I am basically trying to load the html in Excel and have all the outputs in different worksheets (one per SQL output) instead of doing right-click each time.

I am very new to Excel and not sure how to achieve this.

Could you please point me on how to achieve this?

Many thanks

Comment: Please see [ask] as a starting point.

Comment: Hi...I have tried to search... sorry if the question is not clear. I am looking for something like this : http://www.mrkent.com/tools/converter/ but do not want the steps to be done manually. I am not sure how this can be achieved in excel, but looking for wherein I can load the html file and let excel segregate the sql outputs into data in different worksheets. Any example on how to get this done would be of much help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use a Excel Web Query: See http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pull-data-into-microsoft-excel-with-web-queries/ or search excel web query on Google.
You may provide a URL such as file://C:\somefolder\somehtmlfile.html
You can find more info on how to problematically create and refresh a web query here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa203721(v=office.11).aspx
A better option would be to pull data directly into Excel assuming whomever uses the spreadsheet has read access to the relevant database tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to do it as an automatization, you could use C#.
Where you actually take your website and copy the content from your webpage into a variable in C# and then from C#, you paste it to your position that you choose.
Therefore we use the Clipboard as helper, it allows to copy content into the clipboard which actually transforms any html table into an Excel table.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xls = null;

Excel.Workbook workbook;
workbook = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open("Your excel file.xls", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in workbook.Sheets)
{
      if(sheet.Name.Equals("Which worksheet you want to map"))
      /// the table is converted to html table in clipboard
      string html = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Html); // you actually can give him the HTML code of the table too
      // TextDataFormat.Html can be anyy html code
      File.WriteAllText(temporaryFilePath, html);
      Clipboard.SetText(html);
      sheet.Range(cellmapp).PasteSpecial();
      sheet.Columns.AutoFit();
      sheet.Rows.AutoFit();
}
```

Now if you write from your code a simple `.exe` executable program, you can even schedule it to make it every day automatically.
This is done with `Microsoft.Office.Interop`, but is an intermediaire solution, but maybe not the best to use.